# Spam mail issues through Enquiry forms

Tags: asp.net, contact-form

I have created a Enquiry form using asp.net language and I have inserted Captcha in it but still the client is receiving Unwanted mails on their email id.

What is the solution on this.Please help.

Regards
Pooja

Comment: Please be more specific, the question is too wide. The spam could be caused by other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to check in order to make sure your email is less going to be taken as a spam:

1. Check your subject. Some subject are know to be spam (words and/or typo)
2. Check your content. If too short or too repetitive it can be flag as spam
3. Check your email headers (x-return-path and so on)
4. Check that your IP address is not blacklisted (spamhaus and ice)
5. Check that your PTR is properly set (i.e. mail.your.domain.com should match the IP of your MX and vice versa your IP address should target the same machine)
6. Try adding DKIM or equivalent
7. You can also choose to encrypt your mail using a third party SSL or equivalent.